# Gradle rename package before compile

Tags: java, gradle, package, rename

I have eclipse java project.
Gradle script:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Title': 'xxx' 
    }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: '**/*.jar')
}
def myPackage = 'mypackage'
sourceSets {
    main {
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
    }
}
```

Project file structure

```
src
    com.company.core
                    ....classes
    com.company.impl
                    ....classes
```

In jar file need file structure

```
com.company.core
                ...classes
com.mypackage.impl
                ...classes
```

Need to rename package
company -> mypackge in jar file

It is not android.

Help please.

**UPD**

Thanks, Lance Java.
It working for me.

But there was a problem. All classes from libs (google-play-services.jar, android.jar) come into jar... I need classes located only in src folder... I can to exclude classes by all packages, but i think it is no good solution...

Is there another way whith shadowJar?

My dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile files('libs/android.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be done with the [shadow](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow) plugin

See [relocating packages](http://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/#relocating_packages)